# laravel 8 update form, all field must be updated to run the code. getting error if only single field is updated

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

laravel 8 update form, all field must be updated to run the code. getting error if only single field is updated
this is my productcontroller. I'm new to laravel and vue js . I'm following this tutorial but it seems he didn't try to update a single field.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $oldlogo = $request->old_logo;
        $data = array();

        $data['product_name'] = $request ->product_name;
        $data['product_code'] = $request ->product_code;
        $data['details'] = $request ->details;
        $image = $request -> file('logo');

        if($image){
            unlink($oldlogo);
            $image_name = date('dmy_H_s_i');
            $ext = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $image_full_name = $image_name.'.'.$ext;
            $upload_path = 'public/media/';
            $image_url = $upload_path.$image_full_name;
            $success = $image -> move($upload_path,$image_full_name);

            $data['logo'] = $image_url;
            $product = DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->update($data);
            return redirect()->route('product.index') ->with('success','Product Update Successfully');
        }
    }
```

this is my update form

```
<form action="{{url('update/product/'.$product->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Product Name:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control" value="{{$product -> product_name}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Product Code:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="product_code" class="form-control" value="{{$product -> product_code}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Details:</strong>
                    <textarea name="details" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" style="height: 150px" >{{$product -> details}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Product Image:</strong>
                    <input type="file" name="logo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Product Old Image:</strong>
                    <img src="{{URL::to($product->logo)}}" alt="" height="70px" width="80px">
                    <input type="hidden" name="old_logo" value="{{$product -> logo}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

my routes

```
Route::get('products','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index')->name('product.index');

Route::get('create','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@create')->name('create.product');

Route::post('store','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@store')->name('product.store');

Route::get('edit/product/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@edit')->name('edit.product');

Route::post('update/product/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@update')->name('update.product');
```

this is my error for updating a single field.
**The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<form action="{{url('update/product/'.$product->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method('POST')
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```